# How to rename table name in RethinkDb

Tags: rethinkdb

how to rename table name in rethinkdb for example r.db("rethinkdb").table("data").get("emp100") I want to change emp100 to emp200. how to change that name in rethindb?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the change in the `db_config` table:

```
r.db('rethinkdb')   
 .table('db_config')   
 .filter({ name: 'emp100' })   
 .update({ name: 'emp200'})
```